# Dynamically pull first, last, words from an excel/openoffice cell (and then some!)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

Cell contents:

Epson/Epson TM Series Supplies/H5000;Epson/Epson TM Series Supplies/H5200;Epson/Epson TM Series Supplies/U590;Epson/Epson TM Series Supplies/930;Epson/Epson TM Series Supplies/U925;Epson/Epson TM Series Supplies/U950

I need to pull a resulting cell with the following rules: The first word, the last word before any semicolons, repeating, subbing the semicolon for comma. there could be 4, 27, or 0 semicolons (or any number in between)

the above field would result in an output of 
Epson H5000, Epson H5200, Epson U590, Epson 930, Epson U925, Epson U950

insane amount of bonus points and props if the resulting values were alphabetically sorted somehow
IE: 
Epson 930, Epson H5000, Epson H5200, Epson U590, Epson U925, Epson U950

Column A is about 28000 values long. Results in column B are fine.

If anybody has any ideas on where to even begin tackling this problem, I have run out of thoughts on it.

Comment: Are the "words" always separated by slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you can't easily get your data in another format.  That would be the best solution.

I'm also assuming that your "words" are always separated by slashes.  In Excel, I would write a VBA function for this task.  Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetPrinterModels(r As Range) As String
    Dim arr() As String, arr2() As String
    arr = Split(r.Value, ";")

    Dim results() As String
    ReDim results(0 To UBound(arr))

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arr2 = Split(arr(i), "/")
        ' If words can also be separated by spaces:
        'arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "/", " ")
        'arr2 = Split(arr(i), " ")
        results(i) = arr2(0) & " " & arr2(UBound(arr2))
    Next

    GetPrinterModels = Join(results, ", ")
End Function
```

As far as sorting, you're on your own.  You want to sort the `results` array before calling `Join` on it in the last line of the function.  Sadly, VBA doesn't have a built-in `Sort` function, but there are tons of ready-made sort functions available online.

Comment: I am looking thru excel (I normally use Openoffice) for how to utilize this no doubt wonderful piece of code, any advice for excel 2007 to properly use this?

Comment: I managed to figure out how to use it, at first it was giving an error, but after re-copy pasting, that error was resolved. Thanks again for the help!

for anybody else that might stumble across this, the resource I used to learn how to properly implement this code was http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx